# Aurelia Child Router redirect to specific route

Tags: aurelia

I have a main App router and multiple child routers.  I'd like to have the option of specifying the child route to open when navigating from the parent route.

**Parent Router:**

```
configureRouter(config, router) {
  this.router = router;
  config.map([
    { route: ['','home'],      name: 'home',         moduleId: 'home/home' },
    { route: 'students/:id?',  name: 'students',     moduleId: 'students/students' },
    { route: 'staff',          name: 'staff',        moduleId: 'staff/staff' }
  ]);
}
```

**Child Router for Students:**

```
export class Students {

  configureRouter(config, router) {
    config.map([
      { route: ['', 'home'],    name: 'student-home',           moduleId: 'students/students-home' },
      { route: 'list',          name: 'student-list',           moduleId: 'students/student-list' },
      { route: 'profile/:id',   name: 'student-profile',        moduleId: 'students/profile/overview' },
      { route: 'lockers',       name: 'student-lockers',        moduleId: 'students/lockers/home' }
    ]);
    this.router = router;
  }

  activate(params) {
    if (params.id) {
      console.log("Going straight to a student record for: ", params);
      this.router.navigateToRoute('student-profile', {id: params.id});
    }
  }
}
```

The above scenario (using `navigateToRoute()` within activate) doesn't work, nor am I sure it's the best way.  How can I have the option to navigate straight from the main app router to the student-profile screen if I include an id param?

Comment: hmm, i'm wondering if this is a bug.

Comment: See https://github.com/aurelia/router/issues/89 and https://github.com/aurelia/router/issues/90, the latter sounds like there is a possible work around involving a package but I didn't dig too much into it. I think the child routes aren't loaded yet which is why using the name doesn't work

Comment: Actually I may have misunderstood the problem. Instead of redirecting from the Students page, does this work if you move that to the Home page (the default landing page, student-home)? Also you could move it to CanActivate and return a RedirectToRoute instead of navigating via the router

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I gave up on using named routes with child routers.  If someone else understands them better than me, I'd be curious.  However, I have found it works perfectly to just use the URL routing from any part of the app.

```
this.router.navigate('#/students/profile/' + record.id);
```

Comment: Thanks - this really helped me out.  Exactly what I needed

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use active in your child route. Aurelia router will go automatically to your child route.

```
export class Students {

  configureRouter(config, router) {
    config.map([
      { route: ['', 'home'],    name: 'student-home',           moduleId: 'students/students-home' },
      { route: 'list',          name: 'student-list',           moduleId: 'students/student-list' },
      { route: 'profile/:id',   name: 'student-profile',        moduleId: 'students/profile/overview' },
      { route: 'lockers',       name: 'student-lockers',        moduleId: 'students/lockers/home' }
    ]);
    this.router = router;
  }
}
```

Remove active and in your module "students/profile/overview"
call active(params) to get student from api or what ever you want you can do here with provied params.

Comment: But... how would I use `navigateToRoute` from the parent to access the `student-profile` route of the child?  Or at a minimum, to provide an parameter that allows the child to jump to one of the child routes when it is activated?

Comment: When navigating to a route, if you want to include a parameter in the url, include it as a second argument in the function:
`router.navigateToRoute('students', {id:3242})`
This will result in a url like `https://yourapp.com/students?id=3242`
which you can then handle in your students viewModel however you'd like.